# Is it possible to change mount points of internal storage?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, insufficient-memory

I have an off-brand rooted tablet built on MT8389 with 8GB internal memory. The problem is that manufacturer partitioned this in some weird way making `/data` folder mounted to a partition that is only 1GB large. Basically I have approximately 4GB of free space mounted as `/storage/sdcard0` but it sits unused while all installed apps occupy `/data` making the device close to useless as only core apps after updates eats over 60% of available space.

After all Android is just another Linux flavour, so I would expect I could run console and do this:

1. Copy `/data` to `/storage/sdcard0`.
2. Umount `/storage/sdcard0`.
3. Mount `/data` to the partition that was mounted as `/storage/sdcard0`.
4. Mount that 1GB partition as `/storage/sdcard0` instead.

Is it possible? How to do it "safely"?

Note that I don't want to change partition sizes - I only want to swap mount points or create symlink to make `/data` point to a larger partition. In theory this should be pretty straightforward ;)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to install a script like [int2ext](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2190269) or [Mounts2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.mounts2sd). Note that these use a second partition on your SD card (generally ext2/3/4 formatted) rather than the main SD card partition.

You can also move apps to the SD card (Settings -> Apps -> "On SD card").